# SQL Backing up with SMO & C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, backup, smo

I'm using the following code to back up a SQL Database :

```
void BackupDatabase(string sConnect, string dbName, string backUpPath)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(sConnect))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        dbName = cnn.Database.ToString();

        ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection(cnn);
        Server sv = new Server(sc);

        // Create backup device item for the backup
        BackupDeviceItem bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpPath, DeviceType.File);

        // Create the backup informaton
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup bk = new Backup();
        bk.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(percentComplete);
        bk.Devices.Add(bdi);
        bk.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        bk.PercentCompleteNotification = 1;
        bk.BackupSetDescription = dbName;
        bk.BackupSetName = dbName;
        bk.Database = dbName;
        //bk.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        bk.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
        bk.FormatMedia = false;
        bk.Initialize = true;
        bk.Checksum = true;
        bk.ContinueAfterError = true;
        bk.Incremental = false;

        // Run the backup
        bk.SqlBackup(sv);
    }
}
```

In my system (Win7 x64) it works fine but in destination system (WinXP SP3 x86) I receive the below error :

[image: Exception]

How can I fix it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, you'd need to install the assembly on the server.  Try the SQL Server client installation?

Comment: Yes, I installed `SQL Express 2008 R2` in destination system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the assembly directory on the Win7 machine (GAC) you'll see an entry called Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo. (Browse to `%windir%\assembly`) On my machine it looks like this:

[image]

In my case I'm using version 10.0.0.0. In your case, you will *at least* see version 9.0.242.0 as that is what your program is compiled against (I find it unlikely that you're not referencing the dll from the GAC). If you don't have the same version installed on both machines, you've spotted the problem and you need to update the client library accordingly. I think it's likely that you have a newer version running on the XP machine, since you just installed 2008 there.

If you need more help after checking this out, you can comment here.

Comment: You're right, I'm using x64 version but the destination system is x86. Where can I download the newer version for x86 windows ?

Comment: You want to point this question to Bhaiji. I'm however pretty sure it's a version problem as you wouldn't have been able to install but the correct 32bit or 64bit version on each machine - the installer takes care of that.

Comment: So, how can I fix it ? I mean how I can fix the version problem ?

Comment: I would start by checking out the different version numbers and report them back here, also be sure to let us know if there are more than one version running on either machine. You'll see all of this in %windir%\assembly.

Comment: I've checked `%windir%\assembly`. I had version 9.0.242.0 and version 10 of `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo`. I uninstalled the version 9 from `%windir%\assembly` manually :-( now I get the error in my system too!!! Please guide me.

Comment: Try going back to your solution and remove the references to Microsoft.SqlServer and add them back in, then recompile.

Comment: Thanks a lot steinar.I've done what you say, my problem in backing up was resolved :-) , but now in restoring the database with SMO I get this exception `{"Restore failed for Server '\\\\.\\pipe\\3F103E6E-3FD4-47\\tsql\\query'. "}`

Answer (score 1):

The sql server dll's for 32bit and 64bit are different.

It looks like your project is referencing the 64 bit dll's. When you try and run it on a machine with only 32bit dll's available you get a "file not found" / "could not load dll" type error.

If you want this to work on a 32 bit machine you should reference the 32bit version of sql server dll's.

Comment: you need to copy the 32bit dll's from the 32bit machine to your developer machine and reference them instead of the 64 bit dlls. Note your program will only run on the 32 bit machine